# Images won't show up

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Using cocos2d I put images on desktop and drag them to resource file in my project. It worked before but not any more. Any tips to solve this?

The error:

> 012-08-10 15:30:55.884 again[9753:1be03] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:soundoff.png in CCTextureCache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible reasons why you could observer that behavior:

1. the filename contains mixed lowercase/uppercase; this is typical, since iOS is case sensitive, while MacOS is not; so, it may happen that it works in the simulator, but fails on the device; or, if you rename a file by changing uppercase/lowercas (e.g., soundOff to soundoff), the build system on MacOS will not consider the renamed file as different from the original one and will not include it in the build;
2. the file has not been actually added to the "copy phase" for your target (check the target's build phases).

Hope it helps.