# Couldn't add image fire.png in CCTextureCache, but fire.png is in project..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cctexturecache

I searched all over the internet for an answer to this but it's driving me crazy ..

I'm trying to create a CCParticleSun or CCParticleEffect.. Now I know these need the fire.png and fire.pvr found in the resources folder for cocos2d.. I Have included these files in my project (in the resources file just like all my other images..)

My code goes like this :

```
 sun = [[CCParticleSun alloc]initWithTotalParticles:100];

    sun.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"fire.png"];

    sun.position = ccp(120,120);

    [self addChild:sun];
```

However, When I run my code.. I get these errors in my output :

```
2013-03-27 13:19:25.063 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: OS version: 5.1 (0x05010000)
2013-03-27 13:19:25.065 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
2013-03-27 13:19:25.066 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
2013-03-27 13:19:25.066 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE
2013-03-27 13:19:25.068 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
2013-03-27 13:19:25.068 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
2013-03-27 13:19:25.069 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2013-03-27 13:19:25.069 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2013-03-27 13:19:25.070 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2013-03-27 13:19:25.071 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2013-03-27 13:19:25.071 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2013-03-27 13:19:25.072 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
2013-03-27 13:19:25.072 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO

2013-03-27 13:19:25.073 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: **** WARNING ****           CC_ENABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE is disabled. To improve performance, enable it by editing ccConfig.h

2013-03-27 13:19:25.074 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: cocos2d v2.0.0
2013-03-27 13:19:25.075 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: Using Director     Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2013-03-27 13:19:25.105 Touchz[425:1be03] Retina Display Not supported
2013-03-27 13:19:25.109 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: animation started with frame interval:     60.00
2013-03-27 13:19:25.112 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: surface size: 480x320
2013-03-27 13:19:25.114 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since     image has no alpha
2013-03-27 13:19:26.228 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha
2013-03-27 13:19:26.234 Touchz[425:1be03] -[CCFileUtils     fullPathFromRelativePath:resolutionType:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found: fire.png
2013-03-27 13:19:26.235 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. cgImage is nil
2013-03-27 13:19:26.236 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:fire.png in     CCTextureCache
2013-03-27 13:19:26.237 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. cgImage is nil
2013-03-27 13:19:26.237 Touchz[425:1be03] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:fire.png in CCTextureCache
```

Even though I'm sure i have my fire.png and fire.pvr in my project !! I would post the image of my project files but i dont have 10 reputation points yet.. Anyway , what might be the problem ? any help is greatly appreciated. CCParticle effects are important for any game.. 
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am running MAC OSX 10.7.4 and  I have cocos2d-iphone 2.0 and Xcode 4.4.1

Comment: Search for "cocos2d: Couldn't add image" gives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908844/images-wont-show-up as first result.

Comment: issue is this : [CCFileUtils     fullPathFromRelativePath:resolutionType:]

Comment: you might be having the image in your project but it isnt getting picked up due to some "Path" issue.

Comment: So whats the solution to this ? what can I do ?

Comment: ensure it's adde to the correct target, and not a folder reference